# Better way to create dictionary keys

Tags: python

I have a list of objects which I need to store in a dictionary.  A property of these objects is title, and this is what I am using as the key when I store the object in the dictionary.  I process the title first so that I can use it as the key by removing spaces and truncating it to 50 characters.

However some of the titles are quite long, and the first 50 characters are exactly the same as another title.  Because of this the keys are being screwed up.  Can anyone advise a better method for doing this.  I was thinking about encoding the title in some way and then using that?

Comment: "Because of this the keys are being screwed up" Why are you truncating, then? Just leave them as a whole..

Comment: @NiklasB. is right. Also, why are you removing spaces? You can use any string, including one with spaces, as a dictionary key.

Comment: @David: Maybe for normalization, that would make some sense. However, I don't see how the truncation fits in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to remove spaces or truncate the title to use it as a dictionary key. Python dictionary keys can be any immutable Python type, `str` among them (even long ones with spaces and special characters).

Just use the entire title, or encode the title using a hash:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5('some random title').hexdigest()
'bc847ea8db214557c611c9b3c2f043b1'
```

Comment: I don't see how this would save space, seeing that only references to the string would be stored. However, it would dramatically increase the time needed to lookup a key, because the hash value would have to be computed every time

Comment: First, CPython will store references only to small strings internally. I don't know what the length limit is, and it smells implementation-dependent, so I'm not sure I'd rely on "only references" being stored.  This could save space if there are many large titles (as the original poster suggests) and this dict is ever serialized. Naively, python would store the entire title as key (and presumably again in the value. If the average title is greater than 32 bytes, then the md5 hash above saves space in some cases. As far as this approach being dramatically slower, I'd love for you to prove that.

Comment: Triptchy: Strings are immutable. They will only exist once in memory, unless you copy them. Every implementation I know of works like that (and why would anyone choose the alternative, namely copying big stuff around without a reason?) Can you provide a reference for "CPython will store references only to small strings internally"? **EDIT:** Okay, serialization or storage in a backend DB is the only reason I can think of where this would actually make a difference.

Comment: >>> 'ab'*256 is 'ab'*256
False
>>> 'ab'*10 is 'ab'*10
True

Comment: That's not my point. We are not talking about interning, we are talking about looking up string keys in a hash table, in which case the strings will have the same original location. In any case, if they don't, you'd have to compute a hash anyway for the hash table, which is `O(n)` in either case.

Comment: Regarding performance, please check the following benchmark: http://pastie.org/3910646 Computing a cryptographic hash before inserting the key makes a difference of more than one order of magnitude here.

Comment: @NicklasB - Thanks! Hopefully anyone coming to this question will have enough to make an informed decision about the tradeoffs. Few applications, I suspect, are going to be worried about the performance hit here, and I do like that you can always update a hash with additional information if needed.

Comment: Yes, that sure is an advantage. You can also just use a tuple of immutable objects as a key, which is an alternative in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Just hash the entire title.

```
from hashlib import sha1
sha1('title1').hexdigest()
```

Comment: And then what? A hash table already does something similar, you know?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I'd probably use the PK. But how else do you obtain a cheap, constant length unique text.

Comment: We can just use the string as the key, it's already in memory?